# iphone UITableViewCellStyleValue1 detailTextLabel overlapping textLabel

Tags: iphone, uitableview, label, overlap

I'm using UITableViewCellStyleValue1 in my table and setting some text for both the textLabel and detailTextLabel. In one cell the detail text label is a long URL, which overlaps with the textLabel (normally "URL" and then shortened to "U."), which sucks. Is there a way to prevent this, except from creating my own label and putting it at the same spot where the default one is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the minimum font size for the TextLabel.
[UILabel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth)

> adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the
>   font size should be reduced in order
>   to fit the title string into the
>   label’s bounding rectangle.
>
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL
>   adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
>
> Discussion
>
> Normally, the label text is drawn with
>   the font you specify in the font
>   property. If this property is set to
>   YES, however, and the text in the text
>   property exceeds the label’s bounding
>   rectangle, the receiver starts
>   reducing the font size until the
>   string fits or the minimum font size
>   is reached.
>
> The default value for this property is
>   NO. If you change it to YES, you
>   should also set an appropriate minimum
>   font size by modifying the
>   minimumFontSize property. Availability
>
> ```
> * Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> See Also
>
> ```
> *   @property font
> *   @property minimumFontSize
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the ideal solution as the URL address becomes so tiny that it's unreadable (sorry I forgot to mention this). The better option is to cut off the URL on the right and then I will display the whole text when the user clicks on the cell. So, cutting off the detailTextLabel on the right (like URL http:///www.site.com/somestgg..." is cool, but "U. http://www.site.com/somestuff..." is not!